# Publish message to a topic from Callback function

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Guys,

This question had been already asked, however I am looking for ways without using C++ classes.

Below is my problem statement.

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "std_msgs/String.h"

void chatter_callback(const std_msgs::String::ConstPtr& msg)
{
ROS_INFO("Received the message : [%s]", msg->data.c_str());        
    // Here I need to convert this message other datatypes and publish it to topic "X"
    // Can we have while(ros::ok()) here in this callback function

    while(ros::ok())
    {
          chatter_pub.publish(new_msg);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

ros::init(argc, argv, "listener_v1");
ros::NodeHandle n;
ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("chatter", 1000, chatter_callback);
ros::Publisher chatter_pub = n.advertise<other data type>("chatter", 1000);
    ros::Rate loop_rate(10);
ros::spin();    

return 0;
}
```

Also please note that Publisher is defined in main and being used in callback function. I am afraid this is not the right way to use it.

Kindly let me know if the question is not clear and needs more information.

Updating the code :

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "std_msgs/String.h"

void chatter_callback(const std_msgs::String::ConstPtr& msg)
{
ROS_INFO("Received the message : [%d]", msg->data.c_str());        
   // Convert the msg to the datatype we wanted to 
  
    chatter_pub.publish(new_msg);
    
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

ros::init(argc, argv, "listener_v1");
ros::NodeHandle n;
ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("chatter", 1000, chatter_callback);
ros::Publisher chatter_pub = n.advertise<other data type>("chatter", 1000);
    ros::Rate loop_rate(10);

    while(ros::ok()
   {
        ros::spinOnce();
   }    

return 0;
}
```

Thank you,
KK

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/302774/publish-message-to-a-topic-from-callback-function/) by [kk2105](https://answers.ros.org/users/36026/kk2105/) on ROS Answers with karma: 262 on 2018-09-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The only thing classes add (in a case like this, there are obviously other benefits to classes) is a scope that can persist variables outside the callback's scope.

In your case, without a class, you could use the *global* scope.

---

Edit: two alternatives:

- if using C++11: use a lambda expression and capture `chatter_pub`, then use that in the lambda body
- use `boost::bind` and pass a reference to `chatter_pub` to the `chatter_callback` directly

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-09-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just declare your publisher in the global scope. So, above your callback.
Then, in main, you can loop the way you mentioned, but use `ros::spinOnce()` instead of `ros::spin()`

```
while (ros::ok()) {
  ros::spinOnce();
  loop_rate.sleep(); // Don't forget this! *
}
```

* Thanks @gvdhoorn: Without this, your node would use 100% CPU, even if it has nothing to do.

EDIT: loop_rate.sleep()

---

Originally posted by [snowee](https://answers.ros.org/users/33628/snowee/) with karma: 21 on 2018-09-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kk2105](https://answers.ros.org/users/36026/kk2105/) on 2018-09-09**:
@snowee Thanks for the reply.

So there will be 2
`while(ros::ok()) { ros::spinOnce() }`  ?

One in callback and one in main ??

Thank you.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-09-09**:
This is basically what I wrote, no?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-09-09**:
also: please add a `ros::Rate::sleep()` in your while loop if you're going to do it this way.

Right now your node is using 100% CPU, even if it has nothing to do (ie: there are no messages).

**Comment by [kk2105](https://answers.ros.org/users/36026/kk2105/) on 2018-09-09**:
@gvdhoorn Thanks for clarifying. I was just wondering whether we can have 2 `while(ros::ok()) { ros::spinOnce() }` in a single program.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-09-09**:
Never put an infinite `while` loop in a callback. Ever.

Please clarify why you think you'd need an additional `while`.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-09-09**:
Also: @snowee: why do you suggest to use `while (ros::ok)`? I don't understand how that connects to the question by the OP of how to use a variable in global scope?

**Comment by [kk2105](https://answers.ros.org/users/36026/kk2105/) on 2018-09-09**:
@gvdhoorn I have updated the question with the code. Could you please check if that is the right implementation and my understanding is correct ?

**Comment by [snowee](https://answers.ros.org/users/33628/snowee/) on 2018-09-09**:
@gvdhoorn he asked something about it in the original question

**Comment by [snowee](https://answers.ros.org/users/33628/snowee/) on 2018-09-09**:
The only thing missing in your updated code @kk2105 is the `loop_rate.sleep()` command, as mentioned by @gvdhoorn. I updated my snipped with that.

**Comment by [VishvajeetBhore](https://answers.ros.org/users/53046/vishvajeetbhore/) on 2020-03-31**:
@gvdhoorn : 1)chatter_pub is declared in main function. is it possible to use it in callback function. i am getting scope declaration error. i have not declared the publisher in global scope.

2. i tried it with another way by declaring the publisher in global scope and declaring the NodeHandle object declaration in global scope. I got error as "
   [FATAL] [1585648613.970629312]: You must call ros::init() before creating the first NodeHandle
   [ERROR] [1585648613.971887349]: [registerPublisher] Failed to contact master at [:0].  Retrying...
   ^CSegmentation fault (core dumped) "

Please help. thank you.